# Laravel 9/Passport not working in production

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport, laravel-9

I just deployed a Laravel 9 Passport based API to Digital Ocean. Everything works fine, but when I try lo log an user or an admin and create a token to be stored and returned, I get 500 server error.

I already ran **php artisan passport:keys**. Because it wasn´t working, I tried to pass the keys by .env through **php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config**, but still got the error.
Here is my LoginController:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    
    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Usuario y/o contraseña inválidas'
        ], 401);
    }

        
        // If I comment this line and the accessToken in the json response, and return just the Auth::user(), it works fine
        $accessToken = Auth::user()->createToken('my_token')->accessToken;
    
    return response()->json([
        'user' => Auth::user(),
        'accessToken' => $accessToken
    ], 200);

    
}
```

This is my AuthServiceProvider.php boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    
    
    /* Passport::routes(); */
    
    if (!$this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        Passport::routes();
    }
    /**
     * Controls the expire time for the access token
     */


    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));

    Passport::tokensCan([
        'admin' => 'Admin',
        'user' => 'User',
    ]);
}
```

No errors related are being logged neither in Laravel logs nor in nginx ones.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: A 500 server error should be logged *somewhere*. You can also try turning debug on in your .env for now, since you're still trying to deploy to have the errors written to the screen

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution with aynber guess.
I try catched the accesstoken line and set debug to true.
It was missing the Personal Client ID, so I ran **php artisan passport:client --personal** and it worked.

That happens because the client id is self-generated when you first run artisan passport:install.
But when you are cloning a repo and running a migration and a composer install command, you really never run passport:install, so a new client personal id must be run manually.